# How to catch the message button click event on Slack, and get the input value

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack, slack-api

I am trying to make a small NodeJS project to connect to Slack, post an interactive message, and receive feedback.

My code to post the message:

```
require("dotenv").config();

const { App } = require("@slack/bolt");
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const axios = require('axios');

const APP_PORT = 3001
const LISTEN_PORT = 3002

const { createMessageAdapter } = require('@slack/interactive-messages');
const slackSigningSecret = process.env.SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET;
const slackInteractions = createMessageAdapter(slackSigningSecret);

app.use('/listen', slackInteractions.requestListener());

(async () => {  
  const server = await slackInteractions.start(LISTEN_PORT );
  console.log(`Listening for events on ${server.address().port}`);
})();

app.listen(APP_PORT, () => {
  console.log(`App running on port ${APP_PORT}.`)
})

app.get('/survey', async function sendmessage(){
  const url = 'https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage';
  const res = await axios.post(url, {
    channel: '#test',
    blocks: JSON.stringify([
      {
        type: "section",
        text: {
          type: "mrkdwn",
          text: "Survey"
        }
      },
      {
        type: 'input',
        block_id: 'txt_input',
        label: {
          type: 'plain_text',
          text: 'Response'
        },
        element: {
          type: 'plain_text_input',
          action_id: 'text_input',
          placeholder: {
            type: 'plain_text',
            text: 'Your response'
          },
          multiline: true
        }
      },
      {
        type: "actions",
        block_id: "btn_submit",
        elements: [
          {
            type: "button",
            text: {
              type: "plain_text",
              emoji: true,
              text: "Submit"
            },
            style: "primary",
            value: "1"
          }
        ]
      }
    ])
  }, { headers: { authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN}`}});
});
```

The above code successfully post an interactive message on Slack channel. When user input the value and click button Submit, I would like to catch it and process.
I have read the Slack guide from [Slack Interactive Messages for Node](https://slack.dev/node-slack-sdk/interactive-messages) for how to listen to the event, but unable to success in any of it.

I add the below code to listen to the button event, but unable to catch anything.

```
slackInteractions.action({ type: 'button' }, (payload, respond) => {
  // Logs the contents of the action to the console
  console.log('payload', payload);
});

slackInteractions.action({ type: 'message_action' }, (payload, respond) => {
  // Logs the contents of the action to the console
  console.log('payload', payload);
});
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the `slackInteractions` middleware to your Bolt app:

```js
const app = new App({
  token: process.env.SLACK_BOT_TOKEN,
  signingSecret: process.env.SLACK_SIGNING_SECRET,
  receiver: slackInteractions.receiver
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already use "app" as express. Should i remove that and use your code instead? Or should I make a new variable "listener" with your code?